# Problem with select query in node js and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to request login and registration with node.js and postgresql. The problem comes when at registration and login select the request does not show that I already have a registered person with this email. I'm obviously confusing something with the select query.

```
    app.post('/register/',(req,res,next)=>{
    var post_data = req.body;
    var uid = uuid.v4();
    var plaint_password=post_data.password;
    var hash_data=saltHashPassword(plaint_password);
    var password = hash_data.passwordHash;
    var salt = hash_data.salt;

    var name = post_data.name;
    var email = post_data.email;
    
     pool.query(
       'SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE email = $1', 
   [email], 
   function(err, result, fields){
        pool.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('[PostgreSQL ERROR]', err);
        });

    if (result && result.length)
        res.json('User already exists!');
        else
        {
            pool.query('INSERT INTO public.tutorials(email, encrypted_password) VALUES ($1, $2)', [email,password], function(err,result,fields){
                pool.on('error',function(err){
                    console.log('[postgresql error]',err);
                    res.json("registry error",err);
                });
                res.json("registry sus");
            })
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not handling errors properly. Please handle execution errors in a proper way. Look at the example below.

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE email = $1', ['abc@example.com'], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
  }
  console.log(result.rows)
})
```

Other thing is that you can't use pool.on("error") event to catch execution errors. It is there to catch errors occurring on the connection pool.